# how to parse this json data by javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How parse the data,i want "CC","CT","TT" or rsid , sex .. this data by javascript  ?

thank you all~

```
{
  "0": {
    "rrvalue": {
      "CC": 0.8652407470299768,
      "CT": 1.1161605636753882,
      "TT": 1.4398471271298607
    },
    "rsid": "rs505802",
    "sex": 0
  },
  "1": {
    "rrvalue": {
      "CC": 0.8655216050171408,
      "CT": 1.116522870472112,
      "TT": 1.4403145029090243
    },
    "rsid": "rs505802",
    "sex": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: How about [searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]parse+JSON) before asking?

Comment: And also show your attempts. People aren't here to write your code for you without you showing any attempt or effort

Comment: I'm searching a lot,maybe the method i search is not correct, the related information i searched is not used for me. so i ask the answer in stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
  "0": {
    "rrvalue": {
      "CC": 0.8652407470299768,
      "CT": 1.1161605636753882,
      "TT": 1.4398471271298607
    },
    "rsid": "rs505802",
    "sex": 0
  },
  "1": {
    "rrvalue": {
      "CC": 0.8655216050171408,
      "CT": 1.116522870472112,
      "TT": 1.4403145029090243
    },
    "rsid": "rs505802",
    "sex": 1
  }
}

console.log( obj[ "0" ][ "rrvalue" ][ "CC" ] );
console.log( obj[ "0" ][ "rrvalue" ][ "CT" ] );
console.log( obj[ "0" ][ "rrvalue" ][ "TT" ] );
```

read about how to access JSON/Object values [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp)

Comment: @LeeYang happy to help

Answer (score 0):

**I think this wil help you.**

```js
var data = {
  "0": {
    "rrvalue": {
      "CC": 0.8652407470299768,
      "CT": 1.1161605636753882,
      "TT": 1.4398471271298607
    },
    "rsid": "rs505802",
    "sex": 0
  },
  "1": {
    "rrvalue": {
      "CC": 0.8655216050171408,
      "CT": 1.116522870472112,
      "TT": 1.4403145029090243
    },
    "rsid": "rs505802",
    "sex": 1
  }
}
/* Via jquery */
$.each(data,function(key,value){
  console.log("LOOP  -- >  " + key);
  $.each(data[key],function(k1,v1){
    if(k1 === "rrvalue"){
      $.each(data[key][k1],function(k2,v2){
        console.log(k2,v2);
      });
    } else {
      console.log(k1,v1);  
    }
  });
});


/* Via javascript */

for(var i in data){
  console.log("for Loop " + i);
  for(var j in data[i]){
    if(j === "rrvalue") {
      for(var k in data[i][j]){
          console.log(k + "    " +  data[i][j][k]);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(j + "   " + data[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: question isn't tagged jQuery

Comment: Then use foreach to loop @charlietfl .

Answer (score -2):

JSON.parse method can convert json string to object. See below example,

```
var text = '{ "employees" : [' +
'{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(text)
```

Now obj will be a json object. See it working [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_parse)..

For further reading follow mozila documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)